# SQL where Date from today minus and plus days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have codes like this:

```
  select CUS_Id, CUS_Name, CUS_JoinDate

  from CUSTOMER

  where CUS_joinDate between '04-12-2013' and '06-12-2013'
```

How can I make it 'where' CUS_JoinDate will be declare as from Today Date(minus 1 month and today + 1 month)?

So every time I run the report it will depends on the current date and it will automatically minus and plus 30 days.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try,

```
WHERE CUS_joinDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm,1,GETDATE())
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13578)

Answer (score 3):

You can use CURDATE() and DATEADD()

**[W3SCHOOLS SQL DATES](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 select CUS_Id, CUS_Name, CUS_JoinDate

  from CUSTOMER

  where CUS_joinDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
```

---

However, if you need to add months/years to date, you need to use DATEADD() function.

It can be used as:

```
SELECT      GETDATE(), 'Today'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(DAY,  10, GETDATE()), '10 Days Later'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(DAY, –10, GETDATE()), '10 Days Earlier'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(MONTH,  1, GETDATE()), 'Next Month'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(MONTH, –1, GETDATE()), 'Previous Month'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(YEAR,  1, GETDATE()), 'Next Year'
UNION ALL
SELECT      DATEADD(YEAR, –1, GETDATE()), 'Previous Year'
```

Result Set:

```
2011-05-20 21:11:42.390 Today
2011-05-30 21:11:42.390 10 Days Later
2011-05-10 21:11:42.390 10 Days Earlier
2011-06-20 21:11:42.390 Next Month
2011-04-20 21:11:42.390 Previous Month
2012-05-20 21:11:42.390 Next Year
2010-05-20 21:11:42.390 Previous Year
```